# How to resolve 'Kibana server not ready yet' error when accessing localhost:5601 while Elasticsearch is already running?

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, kibana, data-analysis

when i open localhost:5601 they say "kibana server is not ready yet"
if they are any information

```
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.057+01:00][INFO ][root] Holding setup until preboot stage is completed.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.109+01:00][WARN ][config.deprecation] The default mechanism for Reporting 
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.403+01:00][INFO ][custom-branding-service] CustomBrandingService registering plugin: customBranding
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.408+01:00][INFO ][plugins.taskManager] TaskManager is identified by the Kibana UUID: 7ef89161-828d-42ba-991c-219e3559d7b7
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.517+01:00][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.518+01:00][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.548+01:00][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.549+01:00][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.560+01:00][WARN ][plugins.encryptedSavedObjects] Saved objects encryption key is not set. This will severely limit Kibana functionality. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.577+01:00][WARN ][plugins.actions] APIs are disabled because the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin is missing encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.588+01:00][INFO ][plugins.notifications] Email Service Error: Email connector not specified.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.682+01:00][WARN ][plugins.alerting] APIs are disabled because the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin is missing encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.723+01:00][WARN ][plugins.reporting.config] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2023-05-24T13:02:15.751+01:00][INFO ][plugins.ruleRegistry] Installing common resources shared between all indices
[2023-05-24T13:02:16.202+01:00][INFO ][plugins.cloudSecurityPosture] Registered task successfully [Task: cloud_security_posture-stats_task]
[2023-05-24T13:02:16.525+01:00][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.config] Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, and is supported for Win32 OS. Automatically enabling Chromium sandbox.

[2023-05-24T13:02:16.565+01:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception
        Root causes:
                security_exception: missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]
[2023-05-24T13:02:16.577+01:00][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Browser executable: C:\kibana-8.7.1\x-pack\plugins\screenshotting\chromium\chrome-win\chrome.exe
```

in elasticsearch

```
2023-05-24T12:53:30,804][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [LAPTOP-R3PPI6DP] current.health="GREEN" message="Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.security-7][0]]])." previous.health="YELLOW" reason="shards started [[.security-7][0]]"
[2023-05-24T12:53:31,305][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.f.FileUserPasswdStore] [LAPTOP-R3PPI6DP] users file [C:\elasticsearch-8.7.1\config\users] changed. updating users...
[2023-05-24T12:53:31,307][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.f.FileUserRolesStore] [LAPTOP-R3PPI6DP] users roles file [C:\elasticsearch-8.7.1\config\users_roles] changed. updating users roles...
[
```

what i need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

when you start kibana for the first time you need to create and enrollment token, if you use docker, the command is similar to :
docker exec -ti elasticsearch bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token --scope kibana
And
docker exec -ti kibana bin/kibana-verification-code
This information is updated to your kibana.yml file, you need to keep the state of this file, because the authentification won't work